# sql in oracle to find ratio with grouping by a column

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

Can anyone please help me to find the following by using a sql in oracle

```
Input in oracle TableX --

ColumnA |ColumnB      
1      |20  
1      |10  
1      |30  
2      |10  
2      |30  
3      |20  

-- Desired result 

ColumnA |ColumnB  |Ratio   
1    |20    |0.333333333  
1    |10    |0.166666667  
1    |30    |0.5  
2    |10    |0.25  
2    |30    |0.75  
3    |20    |1  

SELECT
    ColumnA,
    ColumnB,
    ColumnA/sum(ColumnB) group ColumnA by as Ratio 
FROM
    TableX
GROUP BY
    ColumnA
ORDER BY
    ColumnA
```

I can't figure out how to calculate percentage within the GROUP BY

+++++++++
    Explanation:
    Trying to get the ratio by grouping ColumnA
    First row results is grouping 1 from ColumnA like 20/(20+10+30) = 0.333333333
    Grouping 2 from ColumnA 10/(10+30) = 0.25
    last row result grouping 3 from ColumnA is like 20/20 = 1

```
Hence the sum of 0.333333333+0.166666667+0.5 = 1  
sum of 0.25  + 0.75  = 1  
sum of 1+0 = 1
```

Comment: Revised SELECT
    ColumnA,
    ColumnB,
    ColumnB / sum(ColumnB) group ColumnA by as Ratio 
FROM
    TableX
GROUP BY
    ColumnA
ORDER BY
    ColumnA

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `sum` window function to do this.

```
SELECT
    ColumnA,
    ColumnB,
    ColumnB/(sum(ColumnB) over(partition by ColumnA)) as Ratio 
FROM
    TableX
ORDER BY
    ColumnA
```

Answer (score 2):

When functions exist that do **exactly** what you need, it is best to use those functions. In this case, the function is `RATIO_TO_REPORT`. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions124.htm

```
select   columnA, columnB, 
         ratio_to_report(columnB) over (partition by columnA) as ratio
from     tablex
order by columnA  --   if needed
;
```

Answer (score 0):

A window function is the cleanest and gets my vote. For another perspective though, you can also use a subquery to figure out what the total value is for each COLUMNA group. Then, join that back onto your original table and use the sum to calculate your ratio.

```
WITH SUM_TABLE AS (SELECT COLUMNA, SUM(COLUMNB) AS COLSUM FROM TABLEX GROUP BY COLUMNA)
SELECT t1.COLUMNA, t1.COLUMNB, t1.COLUMNB/st.COLSUM AS RATIO
FROM TABLEX t1 LEFT JOIN SUM_TABLE st ON st.COLUMNA = t1.COLUMNA
```